# Unable to quad boot Windows 7/8; Primary partition limitation

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot, partitioning

I'm trying to install Windows 7 x86 and x64 as well as Windows 8 x86 and x64 on a laptop, however, after installing the first three, it will not allow a forth primary partition to be created.  When I installed Windows 7 x86 first, it created a system partition of 100MB as well as the primary partition.  I then installed Win7 x64 and Win8 x86 each on their own primary partition.

I need to have all four installed for testing purposes and VMs will not suffice.  I thought that 4 primary partitions could be created with MBR, however, there are only three listed as well as the 100MB system partition.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 doesn't need that 100MB partition. It is for encryption. You can create normal partition with the OS only. Then you'll have 4 OS. 
Regards
Adam.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your disk from MBR layout to GUID partition table partition style.

According [to this article on msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx#guid_partition_table) **you can have 128 primary partitions on disk with GPT partitions**.

It can be done with windows disk management.

Windows help link:

[Change a Master Boot Record Disk into a GUID Partition Table Disk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725671.aspx)

(there are two ways, command line and windows interface).

Note: Windows XP and older versions have no GUID partition support.